# Aronson's Sequence

Tags: python, function, sequence, infinite

I'm trying to implement Aronson's sequence ("t is the first, fourth, eleventh, sixteenth ... letter in this sentence.") as a function receiving any beginning letter and term-limit (otherwise the sentence can be endless), and returning the sequence.

I've managed to implement this with infinite (t is the first, fourth...) and finite  (g is the first letter in this sentence.) sequences seperately, but am having much trouble implementing both at the same time (in other words having the function work with any letter!).

I'd appreciate some help in figuring out how to do this!

This is the original sequence:

```
import num2words # pip install num2words in terminal
def Aronson_Sequence(letter, term_limit):
    term_num = 1 
    init_seed = letter + ' is the ' 
    while term_num <= term_limit:
        temp_seed = init_seed.replace(' ', '') # we aren't counting spaces
        for i in range(len(temp_seed)):
            if term_num > term_limit: # if term limit is exceeded within for loop 
                break    
            if (temp_seed[i] == letter) and ((num2words.num2words(i+1, to='ordinal') in init_seed) != True): # if letter matches and ordinal ('first') hasn't appeared yet
                init_seed += num2words.num2words(i+1, to='ordinal') + ', '
                term_num += 1
        #if init_seed.replace(' ', '') == temp_seed:
            #break (these commands break out of an infinite while loop, but they hurt infinite sentences because the for loop range isn't modified from inside)
    init_seed = init_seed[:-2] + ' letter in this sentence.'         
    return init_seed
print(Aronson_Sequence('t', 10)) # first ten terms for an Aronson sequence beginning with the letter 't'
```

> t is the first, fourth, eleventh, seventeenth, twenty-sixth,
>   thirty-fourth, thirty-eighth, forty-first, forty-fifth, fifty-first
>   letter in this sentence

Comment: What issue exactly do you have with that code ? Does it raise exception or prouces incorrect answer? Any other issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think this code fulfills the requirements from the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronson%27s_sequence) for this sequence. Note that it differs from the output from your code.

```
from num2words import num2words
import re

def Aronson_Sequence(letter, term_limit):
    sentence = letter + ' is the '
    start = 0
    while term_limit > 0:
        index = re.sub('[\W_]', '', sentence).find(letter, start)
        if index < 0:
            break
        if index != 0:
            sentence += ', '
        sentence += num2words(index+1, to='ordinal')
        term_limit -= 1
        start = index+1
    return sentence + ' letter in this sentence'

print(Aronson_Sequence('t', 10))    
print(Aronson_Sequence('g', 10))
print(Aronson_Sequence('r', 10))
```

The output is:

```
t is the first, fourth, eleventh, sixteenth, twenty-fourth, twenty-ninth, thirty-third, thirty-fifth, thirty-ninth, forty-fifth letter in this sentence
g is the first letter in this sentence
r is the first, ninth letter in this sentence
```

Comment: That's true. Yours is correct. Any idea as to why the difference (sixteen for you seventeen for me?)

Comment: You don't seem to be ignoring punctuation, so I guess that would account for the difference

Comment: @ikavodo Please mark my answer as Accepted if you are happy with this solution. Thanks